# Pass multiple regular expressions to the gsub() function in jq

Tags: json, jq, gsub

How can I avoid doing embarrassing stuff like this when trying to apply multiple regular expressions using the `gsub()` function in jq?

```
."values" | tostring | gsub("\"";"`") | gsub("\\[";"") | gsub("\\]";"") | gsub("=\\w*";"")
```

I want to convert the array below to a string, keep the values to the left of the equals sign and surround each value in backticks.

The jq command above works but something tells me there's a more elegant solution.

Input:

```json
{
  "values": [
    "1=foo",
    "2=bar",
    "3=baz"
  ]
}
```

Output (expected and actual)

```json
"`1`,`2`,`3`"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yet you can use `gsub()` such as

```bash
."values" | map("`\(gsub("=\\w+";""))`")| join(",")
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/PQTQR-ixuVx)</kbd>

Answer (score 3):

- [`split()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#split(str)) on a `=`
- Take the [`first`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#first,last,nth(n)) part
- wrap in ` using [string interpolation](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#Stringinterpolation-%5C(foo))
- [`join()`](https://stedolan.github.io/jq/manual/#join(str)) with an `,`:

```
.values | map("`\(split("=") | first)`") | join(",")
```

---

##### [JqPlay Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/d-dFAhsGqNz)

Answer (score 0):

```
.values
| map(capture( "(?<key>^[^=]*)=" ).key | "`\(.)`" ) 
| join(",")
```